# UITableView Swift questions

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, parse-platform

I want to query using **Parse** to add strings to an array. Then I want to put those strings into the cells of my **UITableView**. However, every time I run the app nothing seems to appear on my table. Here is my code if someone could help explain some of the reasons that it may not be appearing

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate  {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!


var friendsArray: [String] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

    var usrname = currentUser?.username
    var query = PFQuery(className:"Relation")
    query.whereKey("Sender", equalTo : usrname!)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            // The find succeeded.
            //println("Successfully retrieved \(objects) scores.")
            // Do something with the found objects
            if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                for object in objects {
                    var friendName = object["Friend"] as! String
                    println(friendName)
                    self.friendsArray.append(friendName)
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            // Log details of the failure
            println("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")
        }
    }


}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return friendsArray.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = self.friendsArray[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `[self.tableView reloadData];` in the completion block of the `findObjectsInBackground:` call.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` its doing exactly what it name says, specifically its running in the background.

Meanwhile while its running in the background your table view code continues to run in the foreground, effectively in parallel.

So your `viewDidLoad` function will exit and `numberOfRowsInSection` will be called next, but at that time if `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` has not yet finished then friendsArray.count will be 0.

Comment: So what can I do to fix this?

Comment: Similar to this same question yesterday. They are using asynchronous code just in a different place to you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30361517/asynchronous-tableviewcell-data/30361658#30361658. The principle and solution options  are similar.

Comment: Im confused how I can make sure Im running the CellforRowAtIndexPath function after ViewdidLoad, because I would think ViewDidLoad or even ViewDidAppear would all happen first

Comment: In your case when the block completes you could refresh the table.

Comment: How should I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The app does not know when your data will be returned so that you have to explicitly to refresh the **UITableView** once you have successfully received the data. Use `[self.tableView reloadData]` to reload the **UITableView** later on.

The **UITableView** will only load once when **UIViewController** gets loaded. Unless, you have already have data the time when **UIViewController** loads. Otherwise, the number of rows will be 0 at the first time and the delegate method `cellForRowAtIndexPath`  will not be called.

`findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` is an async call when you take a look at the documentation. It's not like its literal meaning that it's running in the background. It means that it won't block the current thread so that users can still have interaction with the application.

Comment: @Kasik Async means that it will not wait for the response to come back on the current thread. It does not mean that it's dispatched to another thread.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your `if error == nil{...}` statement, load your table data like this:

```
if error == nil{
  //All that other stuff...
  tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Also make sure your `tableView` has its `delegate` and `datasource` connected to your view controller. This may require putting this in `viewDidLoad`:

```
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.datasource = self
```

I also find it peculiar that your `tableView` is declared as `weak`, but that may not be relevant.

Try these things and let us know if you're still having trouble. Good luck! :)

Comment: It's `weak` because it's a IBOutlet that is referenced directly from his xib file

Answer (score 0):

just try these things. it will help you
after you get array of element make reload the uitableView. 
if you use storyboard check the datasource outlet
it you did not use storyboard or xib, then you set datasource in coding wisse

Answer (score 0):

hi you can use like this

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell

{


    let cell : UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")! as UITableViewCell


    cell.textLabel?.text = app.str[indexPath.row]




     print(" cell \(cell.textLabel?.text!)")


    return cell


}
```

TableOutLet.reloadData()

Answer (score 0):

- Conform your tableView to its delegate and datasource by written below two lines in your **viewDidLoad()** after **super.viewDidLoad():**

  tableView.datasource = self
  tableView.delegate = self
- Then update this code as below :

  if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
          for object in objects {
             var friendName = object["Friend"] as! String
             println(friendName)
             self.friendsArray.append(friendName)
          }
         tableView.reloadData()
   }
- After that in tableView delegate methods return self.friendsArray.count for numberOfRows() method and also put your code in cellForRow also.

Answer (score 0):

Just place your line after appending elements in array.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()


var usrname = currentUser?.username
var query = PFQuery(className:"Relation")
query.whereKey("Sender", equalTo : usrname!)
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

    if error == nil {
        // The find succeeded.
        //println("Successfully retrieved \(objects) scores.")
        // Do something with the found objects
        if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
            for object in objects {
                var friendName = object["Friend"] as! String
                println(friendName)
                self.friendsArray.append(friendName)
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        // Log details of the failure
        println("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")
    }
}
self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
}
```

Or you can reload table once your final array up-to-date

Answer (score -1):

As mentionded by another hint you need to call reloadData but you need to call it in main thread to see result as soon as possible

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {self.tableView.reloadData()}
```

Comment: He did not dispatch that block of code to another queue, it's just running on the main thread. So, `self.tableView.reloaddata()` is enough

Comment: @LucasHuang I don't know PFQuery but findInBackground does not sound to me as main thread. It can be implemented in way that the callback is performed on main thread but it is unusual. And on the other hand using dispatch_async is almost free of charge and it could not makes thinks worse.

Comment: The reason they implemented always in main thread because developers can dispatch into another queue on their will. If Parse developers put it into other queues, than it's not developers to control it. I don't think that's their style either.

Comment: `Finds objects asynchronously and calls the given block with the results.` They did not say anything on the thread. However, if the main thread is not that busy, iOS will put the task back to main thread as well. So, it's not really necessary for you to dispatch back to main thread.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21122842/whats-the-difference-between-synchronous-and-asynchronous-calls-in-objective-c This post helps a lots. You can consider to change your answer. Although it won't hurt to use this way but not that necessary.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I'm aware of GCD. But invoking async on main queue (dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())) doesn't make sense because you just postpone stucking of UI. And I not aware how to invoke callback on current queue without using deprecated function. Are you aware how to solve it?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get your question. Can you describe in another way?

Comment: Let assume that they are using `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0))` for processing background logic and at the end of the processing they need to somehow invoke the callback closure. How their assure invoking this callback closure on same queue as been used for invoking they function. There is easy way when closure should be always executed in main queue `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) `. But they don't mentioned that closure is always invoked on main queue. So how they invoke the closure on invoker current queue?

Comment: I think you are overthinking it. Parse developers can dispatch to the concurrent queues underlying but it's not necessary because the developers can dispatch themselves and put it back to whatever threads they want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78574/discussion-between-kasik-and-lucas-huang).